display x-axis values in each facet of facet_grid
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
    ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(cyl~.)


How can I display x-axis values in each facet of facet_grid rather than only for the lowest facet?

Add axes="all_x" inside your call to facet_grid() to show the x-axis labels for each facet.

For each facet to display its x-axis individually, you can add axes = "all_x" to the call to facet_grid(), as below:
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~., axes = "all_x")


